# Opencart search product model without full string

Tags: opencart

Opencart doesn't show me if I don't write the full name of the model. I want to search without the full name of the model.

Comment: Where you need admin side > Product Listing ?

Answer (score 0):

public_html/catalog/model/catalog/product.php

LINE 140:

```
$sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%'";
```

LINE: 497:

```
$sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%'";
```